# querystring duplicates it self on server

Tags: c#, server

I have a software that works great when i run it on localhost but when i publish it to the server it kind of duplicates it's on querystring to infinite.

This is the error i get:

```
 HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found

 The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query  string is too long.
```

and here is the url it tries to access:

```
   http://localhost:8084/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252F
```

as you can see it just adds to the same query multiple times.

What could be wrong? is this on the server or is this in the code somehow?

Comment: I mean it works great when i run it locally in Visual Studio.

Comment: If, the length of your domain name is longer than `localhost:8084` that might go beyond **2,083** characters summing up altogether. Your full URL length should never be greater than **2,083**

Comment: nope, we just use the port to access the site

Comment: When i try to access it from outside the server i get this error: 
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Did you host the application on IIS or is it you are just trying to access the application that you run on visual studio directly from other PC?

Comment: Here is my domain name:  http://abcdefghij81.kl.mnopqrst:8084/
and then it tries to reach my loginpage whith is in my accountcontroller and actionmethod is login.
/Account/Login

Comment: Im using IIS on the server. Im very new to IIS so it might be some easy thing i missed

Comment: Did you try to increase the URL Size/Query Length/Request Length? This might help you http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: But i don't think thats the problem. Because i don't want to access that incredible long query i just want to reach /Account/Login as query string.

Comment: Ok. I don't know what caused it but i changed back to an old web.config file and it solved it.

Comment: That sounds good, I may find the reason if you could provide both the web.config files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but I had the same problem and I wanted to point out the solution for others.

My specific problem was that I had a partial view in login page that did not allowed anonymous, so even on login it tries to redirect to login, thus the infinite loop.

Just add

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

on every Action present in login page. (or don't load it in case of anonymous user depending on what you want)